# why have the modified if position in scala?

Tags: scala, coding-style

So I'm learning Scala and came across some examples like this:

```
val doubleEven = for (i <- 1 to 10; if i % 2 == 0)
  yield i * 2
```

Now, what's the added benefit to having this special syntax built into the for loop as opposed to the time-honored

```
val doubleEven = for(i <- 1 to 10){
  if(i % 2 ==  0)
    yield i*2
}
```

style if?

**EDIT:** Of course, the latter example won't actually work. But I was curious why the Scala folks decided to go with a separate syntax.

Comment: The second example give a syntax error. Because `yield` should follow the `for`-loop and not be inside the body of the loop.

Comment: Note that you can also write that as: `for (i <- 1 to 10 by 2)` which is more readable.

Comment: Read chapter 10 in http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contents of file `A.scala`:

```
object A {
  val doubleEven1 = for (i <- 1 to 10; if i % 2 == 0) yield i * 2
}
```

Output of `scalac -Xprint:jvm A.scala`:

```
[[syntax trees at end of jvm]]// Scala source: A.scala
package <empty> {
  final class A extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    private[this] val doubleEven1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def doubleEven1(): scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq = A.this.doubleEven1;
    def this(): object A = {
      A.super.this();
      A.this.doubleEven1 = scala.this.Predef.intWrapper(1).to(10).withFilter({
        (new A$$anonfun$1(): Function1)
      }).map({
        (new A$$anonfun$2(): Function1)
      }, immutable.this.IndexedSeq.canBuildFrom()).$asInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq]();
      ()
    }
  };
  @SerialVersionUID(0) @serializable final <synthetic> class A$$anonfun$1 extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1$mcZI$sp {
    final def apply(i: Int): Boolean = A$$anonfun$1.this.apply$mcZI$sp(i);
    <specialized> def apply$mcZI$sp(v1: Int): Boolean = v1.%(2).==(0);
    final <bridge> def apply(v1: java.lang.Object): java.lang.Object = scala.Boolean.box(A$$anonfun$1.this.apply(scala.Int.unbox(v1)));
    def this(): A$$anonfun$1 = {
      A$$anonfun$1.super.this();
      ()
    }
  };
  @SerialVersionUID(0) @serializable final <synthetic> class A$$anonfun$2 extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1$mcII$sp {
    final def apply(i: Int): Int = A$$anonfun$2.this.apply$mcII$sp(i);
    <specialized> def apply$mcII$sp(v1: Int): Int = v1.*(2);
    final <bridge> def apply(v1: java.lang.Object): java.lang.Object = scala.Int.box(A$$anonfun$2.this.apply(scala.Int.unbox(v1)));
    def this(): A$$anonfun$2 = {
      A$$anonfun$2.super.this();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the compiler creates a `Range` from 1 to 10. Then it calls the `withFilter` on that `Range` to filter all even numbers. And the last step is the call of the `map`-method with the multiplication with 2.

Would your second example work the semantic would be a little bit different. Because it would execute the body of the loop in every iteration without filtering.

It is a matter of taste but I would prefer this:

```
val doubleEven = 1 to 10 filter(_%2==0) map(_*2)
```

Comment: Some others: `-Xprint:all`, `-Xshow-phases` And try `-X` to see more options and `-Y`.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to explain it is that the filtering occurs *before* the body of the for-loop is evaluated, and this syntax is designed to reflect that.

The expression `for (i <- 1 to 10; if i % 2 == 0) yield i * 2`

is converted by the compiler to something like:

`(1 to 10).filter(_ % 2 == 0).map(_ * 2)`

The `filter` comes from the `if`-guard, and the `map` comes from the expression after the `yield` keyword.  It's a mistake to think of `yield` as something like `return` - it's actually just a keyword that tells the compiler to use the `map` method instead of the `foreach` method.  The `map` function can't ignore any of the elements of the collection that calls it, so `filter` has to be called first in order to operate on only some of the elements.

Answer (score 6):

You can think of the `for` construct as a select/from/where query:

```
select (i * 2) from (1 to 10) where (i % 2 == 0)
```

Having the filtering predicate in the `for` section rather than the `yield` one also allows you to use multiple generators and filters:

```
for (i <- 1 to 10; if i % 2 == 0; j <- 1 to 10; if j % 2 == 1) yield { (i,j) }
```

You can do quite a bit without a lot of nesting and sometimes that's handy for readability if the filters aren't too complex.